# I want to make a code that says something when a number is equal to something, but when it is bigger than or less than that number do something else

Tags: python, while-loop

This code started out as a joke, but has become something a little more… I am trying to make this code, but I cannot figure out how to make the code for Pluto print when the number they put in is ‘9’. But the only thing I can get is the code for the if statements… when I want it to print the elif statement… If anyone knows the fix for this, let me know!

```
while True:
  amnt = input('Okay, how many planets are in this solar sytem? ')
  help = int(amnt)
  ast = int(amnt) * 89990189
  howMany = print('That means there are roughly ' + str(ast) + ' asteroids in this solar system!')
  if help >= 8:
    howMany
    break
  if help <= 100000:
    howMany
    break
  elif help == 9:
    print('Um, Pluto isn\'t a planet, you know...')
    howMany
    break
  else:
    print('Please try again.')
```

Comment: if your input is 9 then it will go in your first if (`if help >= 8`) and break out of while loop and hence wont print. You should shuffle around your conditions as bit.

Comment: The logical errors have already been pointer out, but in addition to those, `howMany` is `None`, so it makes no sense. Furthermore, don't use `help` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `help()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have found, for your pluto planet:

```
while True:
  amnt = input('Okay, how many planets are in this solar sytem? ')
  help = int(amnt)
  ast = int(amnt) * 89990189
  howMany = print('That means there are roughly ' + str(ast) + ' asteroids in this solar system!')
  if help >= 8:
    howMany
    if help == 9:
      print('Um, Pluto isn\'t a planet, you know...')
      break
  break
  if help < 100000:
    howMany
    break
  else:
    print('Please try again.')
```

You have already checked for planets above or equal to 8 so that condition is True and in that you will again check that value (amount) is equal to 9 or not in the same loop. It is called nested loop. I have used it. check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution worked! I actually have a degree, I was just coding this as a joke, as I said it turned into something more! But I completely forgot about using a nested loop! Not the first time the answer was right in front of me and I didn’t see it! THANK YOU!!